# SQL Server: join two tables where left table contains all rows of right table in each of its identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to match two tables where left table necessarily contains all rows of right table in each of its blocks!

Well, I just can't describe it better without examples:

Left table contains multiple blocks of rows where each block contains 7 rows, column title has different values in each of these blocks, each block is identified by a number, just like below table:

Table1:

```
objectID    propertyID      title
------------------------------------
0           17020           Iphone
0           17021           7 plus
0           17022           retina
0           17023           2 GB
0           17024           1960 mh
0           17025           64 GB
0           17026           gold

1           17020           Iphone
1           17021           7 plus
1           17022           retina
1           17023           2 GB
1           17024           1960 mh
1           17025           64 GB
1           17026           white

2           17020           Iphone
2           17021           7 plus
2           17022           retina
2           17023           2 GB
2           17024           1960 mh
2           17025           128 GB
2           17026           white

3           17020           Iphone
3           17021           7
3           17022           retina
3           17023           3 GB
3           17024           1960 mh
3           17025           128 GB
3           17026           red
```

and there's a second table having 3 rows in total.

Table2:

```
id      title       propertyID
-----------------------------
1001    7 plus      17021
1002    2 GB        17023
1003    64 GB       17025
```

Now I want to match titles of table2 in each block of table1? again, hard to explain!

**Desired result**:

```
objectID    propertyID     title
----------------------------------
0           17021           7 plus
0           17023           2 GB
0           17025           64 GB
1           17021           7 plus
1           17023           2 GB
1           17025           64 GB
```

Notice that only first two blocks of table1 contains all three titles found in table2. I want a query to compare three rows of table2 to each blocks of table1 not just a row by row comparison.

So if I want to know which 'objectID's are involved, the answer would be

```
objectID
--------
0
1
```

Problem comes where I actually join these two tables using below query:

```
select t1.objectID, t1.propertyID, t1.title
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.title = t1.title
```

**Current result**:

```
objectID    propertyID      title
----------------------------------
0           17021           7 plus
0           17023           2 GB
0           17025           64 GB
1           17021           7 plus
1           17023           2 GB
1           17025           64 GB
2           17021           7 plus
2           17023           2 GB
```

Here the query finds block number 2 of table1 containing 2 titles of table2!
But it must find all three rows of table2 in each block.

Do I even have to join two tables? How can I get the desired result?

Comment: propertyID  with different  title looks bad to me (e.g. red, white, gold)

Comment: Paparazzi, this is a sample data, I made some mistakes in generating that, the real data is correct and way more complex than that. I'm more inspiring by answers than getting the real approach to do my job.

Comment: You should be inspired by data design and accuracy.

Comment: Paparazzi, I agree, unfortunately data design was already done and not in a good way! it's not on my hands, whole company is based on this design. anyway sometimes I get stuck at making complex queries beside this design, just like now. by the way, thank you for mentioning the real concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve by group by and having clause

```
select t1.objectID, t1.propertyID, t1.title
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.title = t1.title
group by t1.objectID, t1.propertyID, t1.title
having count(*) = (Select count(*) FROM table2)
```